# Merge two CSV files in a Gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

This question is a continuation of [How to run a shell command in Gnuplot and place the output in new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519962/how-to-run-a-shell-command-in-gnuplot-and-place-the-output-in-new-file/53521366?noredirect=1#comment93939414_53521366)
 and the example is the same.

In that question, it is answered how to take a CSV file with each data separated by `","` and, remove those characters from the row 8th and, after that, sort the result by the 36th column values.

I have tried the solution, for example,

```
`tail -n+8 Hight_6x6.csv | tr '",' ' ' | sort -nk36`
```

and works fine.

Now, I would like to make the same but with the merged result of two similar CSV files. That is, take the two files from the 8th row, append one to the other and sort by column 36th.

The following line

```
`cat 2x2/Hight_2x2.csv <(tail +8 2x2b/Hight_2x2_b.csv) | tail -n+8  | tr '",' ' ' | sort -nk36`
```

makes what I want to do in the Terminal but it gives an error in Gnuplot. 
The error tells that there is an unexpected '(' character.
The two files to merge are in different subdirectories (2x2 and 2x2b) from where I run the script. The CSV files are in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/266yjqidfmi7mmm/AADpkaGXy8AdKW4MNsCz-eRta?dl=0).

Regards

Comment: The issue is that Gnuplot runs commands with `/bin/sh` which does not support the process substitution, i.e. `<(...)`. You are probably better of generating the Gnuplot script in Bash

Comment: @Thor thank you. There is no workaround to this issue and merge the two files from Gnuplot?

Comment: Enclose the command in `bash -c '...'`, but that is ugly and you will run into serious quoting issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid having to escape single or double quotes, you can use a third form of quoting, the *here-document* to create a datablock. You can then pipe the datablock into a bash command:

```
$datablock << EOD
cat a.csv <(tail -n+2 b.csv) | tail -n+8  | tr '",' '  ' | sort -nk36 >pe_H_6x6.txt
EOD

set print "|bash -x"
print $datablock
set print
```

The `-x` here is just to check the command that gets executed.

Comment: thank you very much. It works well. I see that using datablock allows the inclusion of shell commands. I do not fully understand the three print files, mostly why it is needed the last `set print`.

Comment: Initially, any `print` command just produces output on the terminal. To instead print to a file `myfile`, use `set print "myfile"` first. To return back to printing to the terminal use `set print`. To run a command and print to the resulting pipe, use `set print "| command"`. To close the pipe and return back to printing to the terminal use `set print` as before.